# OpenGL / GLSL Terrain Blending Textures Solution

Tags: opengl, textures, glsl, buffer, terrain

I`m trying to get a map editor to work. My idea was to create a texture array for blending multiple terrain textures. One single texture channel (r for example) is bound to a terrains texture alpha.

The question is: Is it possible to create kinda Buffer that can be read like a texture sampler and store as many channels as i need ? 
For example :

```
texture2D(buffer, uv)[0].rgb
```

Is this too far-fetched ?

This would be faster than create 7 textures and send them to the glsl shader.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [texture array](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Array_Texture) and access the individual textures using texture2D with 3rd coordinate specifying the layer.

Comment: is it possible to bind already existing textures to a texture array ? Cause i may need to use them inside my application